# Packages installed in anaconda but not in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, anaconda

This is what I get after running the code on cmd:

```
conda info
```

I get:

```
conda version 
3.19.3
conda build version
1.19.0
python version:
2.7.11.final.0
```

Now when I run the code on cmd:

```
python -V
```

I get:

```
python 2.7.11::anaconda 2.5.0(64 bit)
```

Now when I run a code in .ipynb it works fine, but when I run the code in a .py file it says:

> no module named pandas.

What is the source of the problem?

Do I need to install the libraries again for running the .py file?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda creates a separate folder (`C:/Anaconda`). Python is installed to `C:/Python27`. If you are running IDLE (default Python editor) you will need to move it to `C:/Anaconda`. I suggest moving all the contents of `C:/Python27` to `C:/Anaconda`, merging any common folders. 
This answer assumes you are running a python file open in an editor. If this is not the case, try typing `python filename.py` into the command prompt instead of double-clicking the file.